# CSS conflict in Disqus Comment system

Tags: css, disqus

I'm using Disqus as my blog comment system. Everything works fine, except the css. I think it's css conflict that adding every `<li>` tag with a small but annoying mark.

And, I've already used the fixing method provided by Disqus official website, that is adding

```
div#disqus_thread li, div#disqus_thread span {
   list-style-type: none !important;
}
```

to my disqus CSS file. However, it still doesn't work. (I would post an image but I don't have enough reputation.)

Comment: can you give the link to the page so that we can see the final css that is getting processed.. ??/

Comment: [link](http://www.xuan-wu.co.cc/?p=18001)

Comment: so sorry for forgetting providing the link~~

Comment: Dear Xuan Wu its not an css issue as per my knowledge it is hardcoded in code with HTML special characters, why i am telling this is because when i remove <li> tag from code the double right arrow removes and when i changes css list-style-type:none to square, circle etc right arrow are also present. so as per my view this is not css issue. please check your code.

Comment: @HappySingh thanks a lot, I really appreciate it. But I still don't know how to solve it. I think my own html code is fine and I can not see the original Disqus html code. So I'm still don't know how to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please remove the code .box ul li:before{ content: "\00BB \0020"; } from style.css

Your problem will solve. Please refer below screen shot for more details.

[image]